# How many Grid walks there are?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let us consider a grid to be a set $G_{n} := \mathbb{Z}_{n}\times\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{n} = \{z\in\mathbb{Z}\mid 2\leq z\leq n\}$. I would like to know if anyone could provide me how many walks exist which pass through every point $(z_{1},z_{2})\in G_{n}$ only once. It is worth mentioning here that just vertical and horizontal moves are allowed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a hard problem in general. [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9500330Y) attacks the case in which at least on side is less than or equal to $5$.